# Group data based on a field and extract the different values in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with 5 fields:

```
1. id
2. text (just a phrase in each row)
3. opinion (holds values: positive or negative or neutral)
4. location (where the person who wrote the text was)
5. label (specific to the text)
```

What I want to do is by using PHP & MySQL get the location of a specific label and be able to show how many positive-negative-neutral opinions there are for this location.

Result should eventually show something like:

```
Amsterdam - 2 positive, 3 negative, 5 neutral
.... - #.., #.., #..
and so on..
```

I want to plot a bar graph with these data, that's why I need it. I thought of using GROUP BY, but for some reason I can't get the result I want.

How can i do this ?

EDIT:
sample on 
[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/beaac1/1)

Desired result:

```
Location    |    Positive    |    Negative    |    Neutral
city1               2                1               2
city2               2                1               0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select
location,
sum(opinion > 0) as positive,
sum(opinion < 0) as negative,
sum(opinion = 0) as neutral
from
your_table
where label = 'whatever'
group by location
```

You have to use sum, not count, because the `opinion = whatever` in it returns true or false (1 or 0).

**UPDATE:**

Well, my query works perfectly: <kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/beaac1/5/0)</kbd>

Of course you have to adjust it to your table and data:

```
select
location,
sum(opinion = 'Positive') as positive,
sum(opinion = 'Negative') as negative,
sum(opinion = 'Neutral') as neutral
from
results
where label = 'label1'
group by location
```

Comment: With this query it looks like I am getting there, but what the result shows is that everything is neutral. For example one location has 31 neutral, 6 positive, 1 negative and with the query it shows 38 neutral only.
Why is that?

Comment: Then the question must lack some information. Please provide sample data and desired result, preferably on http://sqlfiddle.com Oh, and the result of `show create table your_table_name_here`, just to be sure.

Comment: Edited my initial post with adding the sqlfiddle with sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I have given this query based on the assumed values.

```
SELECT count(id) 
    FROM table_name 
WHERE opinion="positive" and location="Chennai" and label="php"
```

This query will give the total count for the given condition.It can be changed to dynamic when you are using it in php.

Comment: I actully want to group by location and not give the opinion as input, but get the opinions for every location.

Comment: @Andrew :Can you provide what are the inputs you are going to provide for this query, so that query can be build easily based on your requirement.

Comment: Edited my initial post, bottom.